# For a row, how to change the value of one column when a value in another column satisfies some condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

Just like what I asked in the title. For example, I have a table with ID and Total. I wanna list all the IDs and Totals if they satisfy that Total < 100. Otherwise, I want to group these rows with Total >= 100 in one row as ID is 000, and Total is the sum of those Totals.

May I know how I can achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **UNION**

```
Select id, total 
From TableA 
Where total < 100
Union
Select 0 as id , sum(total) as total
From TableA
Where Total >=100
```